# Connecting localhost:3000 in vagrant from host machine

Tags: nginx, vagrant, homestead

**How do I connect guest localhost:3000 from host machine?**

So I have set up a Vue project in Vagrant. `vagrant ssh` in and serving the project by `yarn dev` and it shows that it's running on `localhost:3000` in Vagrant.

Here is my `Homestead.yaml` configuration: 

    `- map: consumer.test
      to: /home/vagrant/projects/Consumer`

On my host machine, I have added edited my `hosts` file as following:

`192.168.10.10  consumer.test`

So I went to `consumer.test` on my host machine, but of course it won't run cus the port number is missing, and gives the following error:

`403 Forbidden
nginx/1.13.6`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Okay. I just got it sorted.

**Step 1**

First I have to forward the port number from guest(vagrant ssh) to host machine. This is done through `Homestead.yaml` configuration:

`d
ports:
    - send: 80 (from host)
    - to: 3000 (to guest machine)`

OR

you can add this to your Vagrant config:

`config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 80, auto_correct: true`

**Step 2**

I changed my `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` configuration from:

`192.168.10.10  consumer.test`

to

`127.0.0.1  consumer.test`

**Step 3**

As I'm using Vue (nuxt). I added `HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=3000` in my `package.json` 

`"scripts": {
    "dev": "HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=3000 nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "precommit": "npm run lint"
  },`

Now I just need to `vagrant ssh` in the project folder and run `yarn dev`. On the host machine now I can access it from `consumer.test`.

Thanks